# Is it true to make a question from the part ”its been

Tags: tag-questions

> It's been a long time you have not seen each other

What's the tag question for this sentence?

Comment: With "tag questions", in most cases you just repeat the main verb.  What's the main verb here?  (Hint:  It's in the contraction)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct way of making it a tag question would be

> It's been a long time you've seen each other, has it not?

or you could also say

> It's been a while since you've seen each other, hasn't it?